# Render the Customer Account Navigation Phtml file?

Tags: magento-1.7, navigation, customer-account

I have tried to show the Customer Navigation menu in Custom template file.

Below is My Code:

```
<div id="customer_menu">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/account_navigation')->setTemplate('customer/account/navigation.phtml')->toHtml();?>
</div>
```

The menu is not loading well. Showing like below image

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to add the customer menu via the layout handle?

Comment: @Amasty No, I tried via phtml file.

Comment: are you want to show in special page???

Comment: @AmitBera yes, i tried to show in Popup

Comment: is pop is coming for which page or all page??

Comment: @AmitBera All page showing this popup.

Comment: is pop is render from ajax ?? if it is not call then used my answer

Comment: from where you want to this navigation??

Comment: @AmitBera All pages header showing one link, this link click customer the navigation are showing in that popup box.

Answer (score 5):

The result you are getting is normal. 
The block with alias `customer/account_navigation` does not actually contain the customer account links.
It acts only as a container where other layout files / modules can add links.
If you use a new instance of the block this one will not contain any links.
What I suggest is to add the following code to the layout handle of your page:

```
<update handle="customer_account" />
```

This will automatically load the layout directives for the customer account, including the navigation links.
You won't even need to add any html. The block will be displayed on the left sidebar.

Comment: it's same question. But, don't know in M2. Could you please help me? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/323663/77631

Answer (score 0):

You can add link to your module in the same way as default reviews module does:

```
<customer_account>
    <!-- Mage_Review -->
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try of below code

add a event

```
<frontend>

<events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <mymodule>
                        <class>mymodulemodel/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                    </mymodule>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
         <events>
</frontend>
```

and observer code

```
 public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
{
    $loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();

    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
       ->addHandle('customer_account');
}
```

And it is show in all page Where left panel is exist in layout

If you want to show

in call page then create new layout

```
   <customer_account_custom translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
       <reference name="yourlayoutreferce">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_custom>
```

and  change in

```
observer  $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
       ->addHandle('customer_account_custom');
```