# Magento 2.3.x : Add My Account Dashboard All Links into Top Links

Tags: magento2, customer-account, account-dashboard

I want to display all that links inside top link also which display in my account section.

How to display that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding of how to organize header links, the following documentation link might help you.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html

Comment: I already know about that. But, I have no solution for add all that links which is inside siderbar.main in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

first override file to your theme
Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

and add this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-logout-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Logout</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I need all dashboard links inside top.links.

Comment: hm okey, may be you must move url menu dashboard using javascript or edit phtml top.link add them manually